# Centering specific column in RadListView (Telerik, Winforms)

Tags: c#, telerik, radlistview

I'm using a (Telerik) RadListView  (Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListView()) in my project.
The listview has a few columns:

```
public MainForm()
{
    Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListViewDetailColumn newColumn;
    InitializeComponent();

    newColumn = new ListViewDetailColumn("ID", "ID");
    newColumn.Width = 250;
    newColumn.Visible = false;
    this.MyListView.Columns.Add(newColumn);

    newColumn = new ListViewDetailColumn("Name", "Name");
    newColumn.Width = 250;
    newColumn.Visible = true;
    this.MyListView.Columns.Add(newColumn);

    newColumn = new ListViewDetailColumn("Description", "Description");
    newColumn.Width = 250;
    newColumn.Visible = true;
    this.MyListView.Columns.Add(newColumn);

    newColumn = new ListViewDetailColumn("Costs", "Costs");
    newColumn.Width = 250;
    newColumn.Visible = true;
    this.MyListView.Columns.Add(newColumn);
```

I'm populating the listview manually by adding ListViewDataItems to it:

```
foreach (Data.Tablename listEntry in ListOfTableEntries)
{
    ListViewDataItem newRow = new ListViewDataItem(listEntry.Id, new string[]{ listEntry.Name, listEntry.Description, listEntry.Costs});
    this.MyListView.Items.Add(newRow);
}
```

So far so good. What I did not find out though is how I can format specific columns that are making up the added row. For example: Right-align  the costs.
How can I do that (without also right-aligning all other columns)?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide full code because I got the error from "ListViewDetailColumn".

Comment: What error did you get? (I saw I had a writing error at: "Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListViewDetailColumn" when I rewrote the code to display it here, but else I didn't see any errors in the shown code parts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
   private void radListView1_CellFormatting(object sender, ListViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
   {
    if ((e.CellElement).Data.HeaderText == "ID")
    {
        if ((e.CellElement is DetailListViewDataCellElement))
        {
            e.CellElement.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.TopRight;
        }
    }
    if ((e.CellElement).Data.HeaderText == "Name")
    {
        if ((e.CellElement is DetailListViewDataCellElement))
        {
            e.CellElement.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        }

    //end so on
    }
}
```

Comment: That works very nicely (I'm using .Name in the end program instead of .Headertext as the later can vary due to localization, but functions very nicely that way). Tnx